# Routing config.yml

Tags: silverstripe

I have a contact page which contains contacts. When clicking on a contact a detailed page with this contact information should appear.

The detail page is called in the general contact page:

```
 <a href="{$Top.URLSegment}/contact/{$ID}">Details</a>
```

In the config.yml i added the following:

```
Name: mySite
After: framework/routes#coreroutes 
---
Director:
  rules:
    'detail/contact/$ID': 'ContactDetailPage_Controller'
```

---

// The Contact Detail controller

```
class ContactDetailPage_Controller extends Page_Controller {
    private $id;

    public function init() {
       parent::init();
       $Params = $this->getURLParams();
       $URLSegment = Convert::raw2sql($Params['ID']);
       $this->id = $URLSegment;
   }
```

Unfortunately by clicking on the link an error appears that the current page doesn't exist.

What could be wrong?
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Link:

```
<a href="detail/contact/{$ID}">Details</a>
```

config.yml:

```
Director:
  rules:
    'detail//$Action/$ID': 'ContactDetailPage_Controller'
```

ContactDetailPage_Controller:

```
private static $allowed_actions = array(
    'contact'
);
public function contact( $arguments ) {
    var_dump( $arguments->allParams() );
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you! I made a ContactDetailPage.ss - But by calling the Details link above i get a blank page, which gives me just the array with the passed parameters. How would it be possible to call the right .ss (assign the right template)?